# comparing string to class list in python

Tags: python, string, list, compare

I am trying to figure out how to compare a string to the 0th element in the list (technically the bottom). The list is also a class instance and looks like this:

```
#define class called GEL
class GEL:
    def __init__(self,eventtime,type):
            self.eventtime=eventtime
            self.type=type

myList=[]
```

And when I add something to the list:

```
myList.append(GEL(time,type))  ##Type can be either 'Arrival' or 'Departure'
```

For which the list will be (1.343432,'Arrival')
So I want to compare 'Arrival' with the type item in the list.

```
for i in range(5):    ##loop for insertions and deletions
     Type=[a.type for a in myList] ##Actually goes to the last type, but want first
     if 'Arrival' in Type:
            ##DO STUFF
     else:
          ##HELLO WORLD
     #sortlist
     myList.pop(0)
```

What would be the correct way just get the first type in the list?

Sorry for the poor jargon, am still learning Python.

EDIT: I think I may have solved. It gets me what I want. If anyone could tell me if this would be ok:

```
if 'Arrival' in Type[0]:
```

Comment: Actually, I think I might have just solved the problem

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), Post your answer as (well obviously,) an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need this

```
if mylist[0].type == 'Arrival':
```